# jquery: find a particular string of text within a selected value

Tags: jquery

I am using the code below to hide/show sections based on the selection from a dropdown.  I want to say, if the value selected **contains** the word "**-AREA**" continue with the code.  How do I include a find/search of a particular string with this code base?

```
$('select#7535').change(function(event) { 
        var campaignType = $(this).val();
           if (campaignType == "Type 1")
           {
               $('tr.tr-1153-7548').show();
               $('tr.tr-1153-7549').show(); 
           }
           else 
           {
               $('tr.tr-1153-7548').hide();
               $('tr.tr-1153-7549').hide(); 
           }
});
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: have you tried indexOf() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`String#indexOf`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.7) searches for a substring within a string, so:

```
if (campaignType.indexOf("-VIEW") !== -1) {
    // It's there
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the `indexOf` method for this.

I am not sure what your "selected value" is, but assuming it is `campaignType` then you can do it like so:

```
var contains = campaignType.indexOf("-AREA") > -1;
```

`contains` will the be a boolean value (true/false) which you can use for testing.

Comment: That's not what `substring` does.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: yeah, yeah... head thinking indexOf, fingers typing something else as usual!